# Strange characters when extracting text from html

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am extracting some text from html which is passed as a string. The format of the text extracted is strange. It should be in Arabic but is showing strange characters when extracted. I have commented the code to make it easy to understand. Overall what the code does it to find out the characterset of the html passed e.g. (utf, windows-1256), then load the document in the approprate manner. Use html node parsing to find the required html elements in a loop and extract each one's required text.

The problem is the two statements within the if statements works

```
$html =  @iconv('windows-1256', 'windows-1256', $html);
@$doc->loadHTMl($this->metaUtf8. $html);
```

And the following statement after that which is commented out shows the gibberish text which should not be so and should work without the above 2 statements. So what could be the reason?

```
//@$doc->loadHTMl($this->metaWindows1256. $html);
```

The code:

```
    //strings declared that will appended to html when loading the doc
    public $metaWindows1256 = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256"/>' ;
    public $metaUtf8 = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>' ;

    //extract characterset of html passed in variable $html
    preg_match( '@<meta\s+http-equiv="Content-Type"\s+content="([\w/]+)(;\s+charset=([^\s"]+))?@i', $html, $matches );
    if ( isset( $matches[3] ) )
    {
        $charset = $matches[3];
    }

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    if(!($charset=='UTF-8') && !($charset=='utf-8'))
    {

            $html =  @iconv('windows-1256', 'windows-1256', $html);
            @$doc->loadHTMl($this->metaUtf8. $html);
        //@$doc->loadHTMl($this->metaWindows1256. $html);
    }
    else
    {
            echo 'LOADING UTF';
        @$doc->loadHTMl($this->metaUtf8. $html);
    }

    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName($element_tagname) as $element)
    {
        if (substr_count($element->getAttribute($attribute),$value)!=0) //if the title of the div contains 'post_message'
        {
            $found_element[]= $element->getAttribute('href');
            $found_element[]= $element->nodeValue;
            $found_elements[] = $found_element;
            unset($found_element);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Try to avoid use of the @ operator. It can have quite an impact on performance, and it makes your life far harder than it needs to be when it comes to debugging code.  You're far better off using error_reporting, display_errors and log_errors PHP settings or ini_set calls to configure error message outputting.

Comment: why do you use `iconv` with two same encodings?

Comment: @Marek Sebera: Its strangely does not work without that. Get those strange characters

Comment: The problem is solved, my answer is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I was converting the html from windows1256 to utf in some other part of the code. Now when I was checking the characterset again of the html using its meta it would ofcourse say that it is windows1256 although I would have converted it already to utf. So Later I was again trying to covert it to utf again and so the strange characters.

Thanks anyway

Comment: @TRiG - it asked me to wait for two days

Comment: @Imran: It's been more than two days.